# Fast algorithm to find minimum path for disconnected edges

Tags: python, algorithm

Hi I have adjacency matrix for a directed graph:

```
∞   12  0   28  0   0   0
12  ∞   10  43  0   0   0
0   10  ∞   0   10  0   0
28  43  17  ∞   0   0   0
0   31  10  0   ∞   8   0
0   0   0   0   14  ∞   6
0   0   0   0   0   6   ∞
```

here we have some edges that are not connected directly and i want to replace zeros with minimum path between edges. The expected output:

```
∞   12  22  28  32  40  46
12  ∞   10  40  20  28  34
22  10  ∞   50  10  18  24
28  27  17  ∞   27  35  41
32  20  10  60  ∞   8   14
46  34  24  74  14  ∞   6
52  40  30  80  20  6   ∞
```

is there any fast python solution for that?(note that graph is directed)

Comment: Usually a node is connected to itself with length 0, and when two nodes are not connected, their distance is infinity. Look for "all pairs shortest path", specifically Floyd-Warshall algorithm for dense graphs with possibly negative edges, Johnson's algorithm, or just run Djikstra from each node since all edges are positive.

Comment: Do you want only the 0s to be replaced? Note that some direct edges may not be the shortest path between two nodes.

Comment: The test case shows a direct edge being replaced by a shorter path. (second column, fourth row).  If you know all edges will be positive, use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) and [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/) make this very simple.

First, define the adjacency matrix. As Kenny Ostrom noted, the diagonal is conventionally 0 (more on that later):

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

am = np.array([[0,   12,  0,   28,  0,   0,   0],
    [12,  0,   10,  43,  0,   0,   0],
    [0,  10,  0,   0,   10,  0,   0],
    [28,  43,  17,  0,   0,   0,   0],
    [0,   31,  10,  0,   0,   8,   0],
    [0,   0,   0,   0,   14,  0,   6],
    [0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   6,   0]])
```

Now find the shortest distances:

```
dists = nx.floyd_warshall_numpy(nx.from_numpy_matrix(am, create_using=nx.DiGraph()))
```

(Many thanks to @curious_cat for pointing out the need for `create_using=nx.DiGraph()`, BTW.)

Finally, you can replace the 0 entries by the distances you found:

```
>>> np.where(am, am, dists)
array([[  0.,  12.,  22.,  28.,  32.,  40.,  46.],
       [ 12.,   0.,  10.,  43.,  20.,  28.,  34.],
       [ 22.,  10.,   0.,  50.,  10.,  18.,  24.],
       [ 28.,  43.,  17.,   0.,  27.,  35.,  41.],
       [ 32.,  31.,  10.,  60.,   0.,   8.,  14.],
       [ 46.,  34.,  24.,  74.,  14.,   0.,   6.],
       [ 52.,  40.,  30.,  80.,  20.,   6.,   0.]])
```

If you want the diagonal to be something else (which makes less sense to me, I must say), you can use [`np.fill_diagonal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html).

Comment: Naive question; why are the last two entries of the first row (46,52) in your solution and (40,46) in his?

Comment: Hmmm ok, so take the pair of nodes (1,6). His answer is 40 and yours is 46. 40 seems right to me, just by my naive observation. i.e. Go from node 1 to 2 to 3 to  5 to 6. I get  a distance of 12 + 10 + 10 + 8 = 40. Why is this not the shortest path?

Comment: No, with zero indexing shouldn't the (0,5) entry be 40 too?

Comment: @curious_cat Many thanks for your comments - appreciated! The resulting matrix is now identical to the required one in the question.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help! PS. Can you add some comments about what your initial error was? Without create_using what does the call do?

Comment: @curious_cat Without it, apparently it can decide that an upper-triangular entry is the one in the corresponding lower-triangular transposed position. If you notice, there's an 8 in a "symmetric around the diagonal" to the 14. It was replaced by the 14 (which added a 6 to the subsequent results). Thanks again!